# MySQL find duplicate rows in UNION table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

How can I find duplicate email on below query?

```
SELECT b_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND b_email != '' 
UNION (SELECT c_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND c_email != '') 
UNION (SELECT user_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND user_email != '') 
UNION (SELECT user_email AS email FROM sub_user WHERE status = 3 AND user_email != '') 
UNION (SELECT su_email AS email FROM sub_user WHERE status = 3 AND su_email != '') 
ORDER BY email ASC
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query results won't have duplicates because `UNION` removes duplicates. To preserve the duplicates, use `UNION ALL` instead:

```
SELECT b_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND b_email != ''
UNION ALL SELECT c_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND c_email != ''
...
```

To figure out which email addresses are duplicated you could do the following:

- Change your query to return a list of *all* email addresses, including duplicates (this means use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`)
- Wrap it with an outer query that counts by email address
- Limit the outer query results to email addresses that have a count of two or more

Here's how to do it (note this assumes your posted query works):

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT b_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND b_email != '' 
  UNION ALL SELECT c_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND c_email != ''
  UNION ALL SELECT user_email AS email FROM user WHERE status = 3 AND user_email != ''
  UNION ALL SELECT user_email AS email FROM sub_user WHERE status = 3 AND user_email != ''
  UNION ALL SELECT su_email AS email FROM sub_user WHERE status = 3 AND su_email != ''
) EmailGlom
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Your results will be every email address that shows up more than once in the inner query.